# How to detect when an actor is touched in libgdx?

Tags: android, touch, sprite, libgdx

I am using "Gdx.input.isTouched()" in the render method of my Screen method, to know where is touched, but when the touch is dragged in the screen, it also activates the events i want only when an actor is touched.

Is there any listener to know when an Actor is touched, but the event is not the dragged one, im doing it with sprites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this wiki page about [scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) in LibGDX. Specifically the part about Input handling.

Basically you have to override one or more of these methods in your Actor:

```
public boolean touchDown (float x, float y, int pointer) {
    return false;
}

public void touchUp (float x, float y, int pointer) {
}

public void touchDragged (float x, float y, int pointer) {
}

public boolean touchMoved (float x, float y) {
    return false;
}

public boolean scrolled (int amount) {
    return false;
}

public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
    return false;
}

public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {
    return false;
}

public boolean keyTyped (char character) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the outdated comment, but are these methods removed from the current version of Actor? Seems they are missing.

Comment: Libgdx wiki contains up to date info about handling events. See http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d#Event_system

Answer (score 1):

in libGDX `Actor` have a listener inside.
Example if you want check when a button is press, or is check, you call :
`button.isPressed()`, `button.isCheck()`,  it return boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to implement one of the following method to detect only single time touch not the move event perform by the user.

```
Gdx.input.justTouched();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you control in Stage  when you have multi-actors.