# Change Sprite dynamically using Universal Tween Engine

Tags: java, libgdx, tile, tween

In my Tile class, I assign `sprites` to each tile using `TextureAtlas's createSprite()`. Now from my screenLauncher class , I want to change the Tile's sprite i.e. image when I click on the tile.How can I achieve this? Tile class makes use of TweenEngine for animation of the tiles.

My Tile Class :

```
public class Tile {
private final float x, y;
public String title;
Sprite sprite;
private final Sprite interactiveIcon;
private final Sprite veil;
private final OrthographicCamera camera;
private final BitmapFont font;
private final TweenManager tweenManager;
private final MutableFloat textOpacity = new MutableFloat(1);

public Tile(float x, float y, float w, float h, String title, String spriteName, TextureAtlas atlas, TextureAtlas launcherAtlas, OrthographicCamera camera, BitmapFont font, TweenManager tweenManager) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.title = title;
    this.camera = camera;
    this.font = font;
    this.tweenManager = tweenManager;
    this.sprite = launcherAtlas.createSprite(spriteName);
    this.interactiveIcon = atlas.createSprite("interactive");
    this.veil = atlas.createSprite("white");

    sprite.setSize(w, h);
    sprite.setOrigin(w/2, h/2);
    sprite.setPosition(x + camera.viewportWidth, y);

    interactiveIcon.setSize(w/10, w/10 * interactiveIcon.getHeight() / interactiveIcon.getWidth());
    interactiveIcon.setPosition(x+w - interactiveIcon.getWidth() - w/50, y+h - interactiveIcon.getHeight() - w/50);
    interactiveIcon.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0);

    veil.setSize(w, h);
    veil.setOrigin(w/2, h/2);
    veil.setPosition(x, y);
    veil.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
}

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    sprite.draw(batch);

    float wrapW = (sprite.getWidth() - sprite.getWidth()/10) * Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / camera.viewportWidth;

    font.setColor(1, 1, 1, textOpacity.floatValue());
    font.drawWrapped(batch, title,
        sprite.getX() + sprite.getWidth()/20,
        sprite.getY() + sprite.getHeight()*19/20,
        wrapW);

    if (veil.getColor().a > 0.1f) veil.draw(batch);
}

public void enter(float delay) {
    Timeline.createSequence()
        .push(Tween.to(sprite, SpriteAccessor.POS_XY, 0.7f).target(x, y).ease(Cubic.INOUT))
        .pushPause(0.1f)
        .push(Tween.to(interactiveIcon, SpriteAccessor.OPACITY, 0.4f).target(1))
        .delay(delay)
        .start(tweenManager);
}
public boolean isOver(float x, float y) {
    return sprite.getX() <= x && x <= sprite.getX() + sprite.getWidth()
        && sprite.getY() <= y && y <= sprite.getY() + sprite.getHeight();
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return this.title;
}
}
```

I want to know if it is possible in LibGdx using universal tween engine to change Sprites dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier for you if you make your tiles extend [**`Actor`**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) and add them to [**`Stage`**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html) in stead of calling `draw()` manually.

- Position variables will already be there. You can still animate it in the same way and it'll look exactly same.
- Additionally, as you have actors now, you can add [**`ClickListener`**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html)s to them. When the `Tile` is clicked, you can change the value of `Sprite` member and reload it.

You can even refer to [How to detect when an actor is touched in libgdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236175/how-to-detect-when-an-actor-is-touched-in-libgdx)

Good luck.