# LibGDX Input from previous screen registering

Tags: libgdx

I am using isTouched to setScreen from my menu screen to my main game screen.  (Tap to continue).

In the constructor of the main game screen, I set the input processor.  The input processor then immediately fires from the touch on the previous screen.

What is the proper way to handle this?

EDIT: If I tap my finger on an Android device, the tap triggers the isTouched/justTouched.  Then the next screen loads faster than I lift my finger and the finger up event triggers my input processor.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236175/how-to-detect-when-an-actor-is-touched-in-libgdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any built-in way to prevent this sort of event leakage.  One way to avoid the problem is to trigger your transition on release, not press.

1. Switch your main menu to use an `InputProcessor`.  Use the end-of-touch event to trigger your transition, so that event won't be around to pollute your new `InputProcessor`.  This will avoid mixing polling and event-based input, which seems cleaner, too.
2. Set a flag when `isTouched` is true, then in later a render iteration when `isTouched` is false, and the flag is true, you know it is safe to proceed (this is a hacky polling version of waiting for the touch-up event).

In many UIs button events trigger on the touch-up (or its equivalent).  E.g., in this stackoverflow UI, click down on the "Post Your Answer" button, then drag the mouse off the button and release.  The button doesn't "click".  (Similarly if you click outside the button, drag into it, and then release, it still doesn't "click".)

Comment: Thanks that sounds reasonable